# Why does my computer erratically scroll up and down?

Tags: windows-xp, mouse, scrolling

I am running Windows XP with SP3 on a 2002 Gateway machine.

For the last few days I have experienced the problem of erratic scrolling that seems to have a mind of its own. If I am on a window with a scroll bar, the window scrolls up and down the page erratically, often when I have not initiated it. I am not sure but think this started following a routine Windows Update. It is doing it now as I type this. It is totally distracting to being able to do anything while it is occurring. It does it a while then there are occasional pauses in the scrolling then it starts up again.

Any suggestions on fixing this?

Comment: This question has just been migrated from stackoverflow: http://superuser.com/questions/44755/erratic-scrolling. There's no need to ask again.

Comment: He might have misread it as: we closed it here, go ask there ;-) But indeed an exact dupe

Comment: Sorry,
I did not realize it would be migrated over.  I reasked the question here after being told it belonged here rather than at stackoverflow.

Comment: No problem. When a question gets migrated all you have to do is press the link where it says "Migrated to..."

Answer (score 4):

Sound like your mouse is toast. Try to clean up the wheel (if it has any).
But once a mouse starts to misbehave, it's time for a new one.

Comment: I don't believe it is my mouse.  This does this when my mouse is not being touched.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: same problem with me. do not assume, just DISCONNECT or REPLACE the mouse and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks!  I will disconnect the mouse when this occurs again and see what the affect is.

Comment: please do, and then report back :)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem for several months with a Logitech 325 wireless mouse.

I tried every suggestion in the book and nothing seemed to work until I found an [article 321122 from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321122) about problems with a wireless mouse. The thing that caught my eye was this statement "Be aware that items such as desktop fans, metal furniture, and fluorescent lights may interfere with the signal from the pointing device."

I looked around my desktop and realized I had recently bought a gooseneck lamp to give me more light on my keyboard. So I moved the lamp over about a foot, and I haven't had any more erratic mouse problems.

I don't understand it, but it worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your keyboard. One or some of the keys is stuck causing it to do that. Try cleaning the keyboard or plug in a different keyboard and see if that works before you do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

My Microsoft wireless keyboard is the culprit. Unplugging the usb "transmitter" stopped the scrolling.